# How to delay image apperance in surfaceView render()

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, surfaceview

Hello and Thanks for reading.

I am new to SurfaceView and graphics in android and would like to know how to delay the appearance of my images by say 15 seconds each.  I am assuming I would put the delay in the render() method....I have been trying for loops with a 15sec count but no luck yet.

```
public void render(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        droid.draw(canvas);

        droid2.draw(canvas);

        droid3.draw(canvas);


    }
```

How would I accomplish the delay of the render and if not in the render() method then where should I make my modifications.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it, but i think it should work. It works in pure java.

```
    // on init
    long beginTime, timeTaken;
    beginTime = System.nanoTime();


    public void render(Canvas canvas) {

            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            droid.draw(canvas);

            if(timeTaken > 15000000000L)
            droid2.draw(canvas);

            if(timeTaken > 30000000000L) // both in nanoseconds
            droid3.draw(canvas);

            timeTaken = System.nanoTime() - beginTime;

        }
```

I guess it should work.

Comment: Works beautifully !!!  much better than doing a for loop count.  Thanks, I did not know this was an option.